# Yii clientScript/assetManager issue when registering/rendering package

Tags: php, yii, assets

I am having an issue with the clientScript and assetManager. I'm publishing a directory of files and then adding a package which I later register. The package gets added just fine but when it gets rendered the url is wrong.

Publishing the files and adding the package:

```
// Publish the directory
$scriptFiles = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('library').'/assets/jquery.plugins/jquery.dropdown/', true, 0);

// Add the package
Yii::app()->clientScript->packages = array(
        'jquery.dropdown'=>array(
                'baseURL'=>$scriptFiles,
                'js'=>array('jquery.dropdown.js', 'jgestures.min.js'),
                'depends'=>array('jquery'),
        ),
);
```

The package is added just fine and published to a asset directory in the application, this is the output from Yii::app()->clientScript->packages.

```
Array
(
    [jquery.dropdown] => Array
        (
            [baseURL] => /assets/a4017faa
            [js] => Array
                (
                    [0] => jquery.dropdown.js
                    [1] => jgestures.min.js
                )
            [depends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => jquery
                )
        )
)
```

Although, when I register the package width Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('jquery.dropdown') this is what gets rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/961fc04/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/961fc04/jgestures.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the URL in the src attribute, wrong directory. Have anyone encountered this before and/or know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with the following

```
$scriptFiles = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('library').'/assets/jquery.plugins/jquery.dropdown/', true, 0);
```

The package manager actually publishes the package for you, so what you're doing here is publishing the same file twice. Set `$scriptFiles` to `Yii::getPathOfAlias('library').'/assets/jquery.plugins/jquery.dropdown/` instead and it should work fine.

[Here's a basic article](http://danaluther.blogspot.se/2012/03/using-packages-with-clientscript.html) on Yii packages, if you feel like doing some more reading.

EDIT: I see now that you've tried setting `baseUrl` to avoid the auto publishing, you have however spelled it `baseURL`, this makes Yii auto publish it instead of using the path you want to give it.

Comment: Thanks, this solved one of the issues, also had to use an alias in the basePath.